# Vector Bernstein inequality for average of vector-valued random variables

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, concentration-of-measure

I am reading the proof of Lemma 18 in Appendix A in [1]:
[image]

To prove this lemma the author starts with the vector Bernstein inequality Theorem 12 in [2]:

[image]

Theorem 12 is established for $y = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ where $x_i$ is a vector-values random variable. Then, for $z = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$, in the end of the proof of Lemma 18 in [1], the author justifies that the Bernstein inequality in Theorem 12 in [2] can be written as

$$P(\|z \| \geq \epsilon ) \leq \exp \left\{-n\frac{\epsilon^2}{8\sigma^2}+ \frac{1}{4}\right\}\tag{1}$$ by utilizing $V \leq \frac{1}{n}\sigma^2$. I do not understand the connection here. Could you please someone provide more details on how $(1)$ is derived?

<sup>[1] Jonas Moritz Kohler, Sub-sampled Cubic Regularization for Non-convex optimization, 2017</sup>

<sup>[2] David Gross, Recovering Low-Rank Matrices From Few Coefficients In Any Basis, 2010</sup>

Comment: The right bound for $V$ after (1) is $V \le n\sigma^2$.

Comment: @YuvalPeres thank you very much of the response. Is it possible to provide some more details how $V \le n\sigma^2$ is derived? Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: The variance of a sum of independent variables is the sum of the variances. This is also true for vector-valued variables.

Comment: I think in the paper they did some unnecessary calculations to justify the bound of $Var(z)$, which can be replaced simply by plugging in $n\varepsilon$ into Thm 12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We assume that $m=n$.
Using the correct bound $V \le n\sigma^2$, separate two cases.

$(1)$ If $n\epsilon \le \sqrt{V}$ then $\frac{n\epsilon^2}{8\sigma^2}\le \frac{n^2\epsilon^2}{8V}\le \frac18$,
so $(1)$ is vacuously true.

$(2)$ If $n\epsilon = \sqrt{V}+t$ with $t >0$, then
$$\frac{ n\epsilon^2} {8\sigma^2}-\frac14 \le \frac{n^2\epsilon^2}{8V}-\frac14 =\frac{(V+2t\sqrt{V}+t^2)-2V}{8V} \le \frac{2t^2}{8V}=\frac{t^2}{4V} \,,$$
using $(\sqrt{V}-t)^2 \ge 0$ in the second inequality.
Thus by Theorem 12,
$$
P(\|z\| \ge \epsilon)=P(N \le n\epsilon) \le \exp\Bigl(-\frac{t^2}{4V} \Bigr) \le \exp\Bigl( -\frac{ n\epsilon^2} {8\sigma^2}+\frac14 \Bigr) \,.
$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer! In case $(1)$ of your answer, if $\frac{n\epsilon^2}{8\sigma^2}\le \frac18$ then $\frac14 - \frac{n\epsilon^2}{8\sigma^2}\ge \frac18$. Given that why $P(\|z\| \geq \epsilon) \leq \exp(-n \frac{\epsilon^2}{8\sigma^2} + \frac{1}{4})$ is satisfied? Could you please provide some more information?

Comment: @darkmoor Every Probability is at most 1